# How to define linker variables for emulated Xilinx Zynq

Tags: linker-errors, xilinx, freertos, zynq

I am trying to build FreeRTOS with TCP libraries for Xilinx Zynq ZC702, though I want to emulate the image with QEMU.

I am following the steps described [here](https://freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/TCP_Networking_Tutorial_Adding_Source_Files.html) and resolved other issues that arose. Currently I am facing an issue with undefined variables during the linking stage. The specific error message is

```
../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS-Plus/Source/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/portable/NetworkInterface/Zynq/uncached_memory.o: In function `vInitialiseUncachedMemory':
uncached_memory.c:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `_end'
uncached_memory.c:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `_end'
../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_A9_Zynq_ZC702/RTOSDemo_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/standalone_v6_6/src/xil_cache.o: In function `Xil_L1DCacheInvalidate':
xil_cache.c:(.text+0x75c): undefined reference to `_stack_end'
xil_cache.c:(.text+0x760): undefined reference to `_stack_end'
xil_cache.c:(.text+0x768): undefined reference to `__undef_stack'
xil_cache.c:(.text+0x76c): undefined reference to `__undef_stack'
../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_A9_Zynq_ZC702/RTOSDemo_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/standalone_v6_6/src/xil_cache.o: In function `Xil_L2CacheInvalidate':
xil_cache.c:(.text+0xf98): undefined reference to `_stack_end'
xil_cache.c:(.text+0xf9c): undefined reference to `_stack_end'
xil_cache.c:(.text+0xfa4): undefined reference to `__undef_stack'
xil_cache.c:(.text+0xfa8): undefined reference to `__undef_stack'
../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Demo/CORTEX_A9_Zynq_ZC702/RTOSDemo_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/libsrc/standalone_v6_6/src/xil_mmu.o: In function `Xil_SetTlbAttributes':
xil_mmu.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `MMUTable'
xil_mmu.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `MMUTable'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:167: recipe for target '../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/freertos.elf' failed
make: *** [../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/freertos.elf] Error 1
```

Where should I define these variables since the system will be emulated?

The Zynq network specific files can be found [here](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/tree/9a25860e761036a9eb780799c9db632e3eff60c9/portable/NetworkInterface/Zynq)

Comment: I'd guess it's looking for memory region boundaries, which are usually defined in the linker script.

Comment: That is, you are not using the linker script that is supposed to be used by this code. You can either 1) look for this script and use it as is, 2)  use its content for adding the missing sections to the one you are currently using.  I would personally go for option 1).